# Should a semicolon be used before a clause that's mostly a quotation? For example: he “had the reputation of a good preacher.”

Tags: semicolons, quotation-marks, periods

In the following section:

> His presence was always looked forward to on the Sundays when he filled the pulpit, and he was a ready pastor at the weddings and funerals of Milford; he “had the reputation of a good preacher.”

Should the semicolon be replaced by a period, given that, besides the subject he, everything else including the verb in the second independent clause is enclosed by quotation marks?

In the section:

> People felt that he had “gone mad” or that he harbored some “secret sin”; while others felt it was “an eccentric whim.”

Should the semicolon be replaced by a comma?

Comment: All your questions have been about the use of punctuation. You might be interested in the [Semicolon Guide](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/punctuation/https://www.lexico.com/grammar/semicolon) by The Oxford Dictionaries, part of their [Punctuation Guide](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/punctuation).

Comment: Certainly the semicolon in the second quotation should not be replaced by a period, because it does not constitute a complete sentence.

Comment: My general rule is to only use semicolons to end statements in programming languages.

Comment: @HotLicks Then how do you separate long items in a list, some of which include commas?

Comment: @BoldBen - `String[]`

Comment: @HotLicks That's a way of stopping commas in data from interfering with computer code but, if you don't use semi colons, how do you do it in ordinary text?

Comment: @BoldBen - Write like a programmer!

Comment: There are many online guides on punctuating quotations (e.g. [this](https://www.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/topics/zr6bxyc/articles/zn2n8xs)), but if you're at college/university you should ask if there is an official style guide you should follow.

Answer (score 0):

Q1 I'd prefer a dash here (the modern version of a colon) as what follows is almost a restating (a fairly close paraphrase) of what is said before. But a colon (old-fashioned) or semicolon is not incorrect. And two sentences can be used to add gravitas.

.....

Q2 This is an old-fashioned use of the semicolon. I'd certainly switch to

- Some people felt that he had “gone mad” or that he harbored some “secret sin”, while others felt it was “an eccentric whim.”

or

- Some people felt that he had “gone mad” or that he harbored some “secret sin” – while others felt it was “an eccentric whim.”

But

- Some people felt that he had “gone mad” or that he harbored some “secret sin”. While others felt it was “an eccentric whim.”

shows the use of a sentence fragment (also present if the semicolon is retained); many now accept the judicious use of fragments to add drama.

... These usages can be checked on by searching on ELU for 'semicolon', 'colon', 'dash' and 'fragment'.

Comment: //Some people felt that he had “gone mad” or that he harbored some “secret sin” – while others felt it was “an eccentric whim.”//  Even without dash it reads fine like the first sentence.  2) Unable to understand why "...." marks are used here, when it reads well without them.

Answer (score 0):

The semicolon is used to join two closely related independent clauses. In your second sentence, you have used it to join an independent clause with a dependent one. It is considered incorrect:

> **People felt that he had “gone mad” or that he harbored some “secret sin”; while others felt it was “an eccentric whim.”* (incorrect)

You need to use a comma instead or remove the subordinating conjunction:

> *People felt that he had “gone mad” or that he harbored some “secret sin,” while others felt it was “an eccentric whim.”*
>
> *People felt that he had “gone mad” or that he harbored some “secret sin”; others felt it was “an eccentric whim.”*
>
> *People felt that he had “gone mad” or that he harbored some “secret sin.” Others felt it was “an eccentric whim.”*

Your first sentence has quotation marks in a rather odd place, but that does not affect the use of the semicolon; you do have two independent clauses. It is correct but ungainly:

> *His presence was always looked forward to on the Sundays when he filled the pulpit, and he was a ready pastor at the weddings and
>   funerals of Milford; he “had the reputation of a good preacher.”*

It's ungainly because, actually, you have three independent clauses. The first two are joined by the coordinating conjunction *and*.

I would end the sentence after the first two clauses and start fresh (and move the quotes):

> *His presence was always looked forward to on the Sundays when he filled the pulpit, and he was a ready pastor at the weddings and
>   funerals of Milford. He had the reputation of a "good preacher.”*

Note that while colons and semicolons go outside the end quote, in American English periods and commas go inside the end quote.

---

Further reading: [Grammarly: Semicolon](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/semicolon/)

Answer (score 0):

Uh-oh. The semicolon wars.

In your first example, it's simply a matter of style. The writers want the thoughts to be more closely connected than they would be as separate sentences.

It's a device that some people love and others hate. It was done more often a hundred years ago than it is now.

In your second example, I agree: It should be a comma.

(And now you know which side I'm on. I use *colons* to connect thoughts more closely than they would be as separate sentences. . . .)